# jQuery add div to another page

Tags: php, jquery, html, panel, addition

There's a little admin panel I'm doing and wondering is it possible after clicking a button in a panel to add a div box inside the index.php file with jQuery?

If so, a little example would be appreciated!

Comment: Google will answer this question very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to send an XML http post request using jQuery's [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method, and then have a php file on the server modify the index file, or a text file that can be included in the index file:

```
$.post('indexEdit.php', {info: "info to ad to file"}, function(data){ /*callback here*/ });
```

Make sure the indexEdit.php has session validation or someone else could could attempt to post information to it and perform an external edit.

Answer (score 0):

To add code to the start of a div, use the `prepend` method. To add code to the end of a div, use the `append` method.

Here are 2 examples for adding code to the body of an html page:

```
$("body").prepend("This is some div added to the start of the page.");
$("body").append("This is some div added to the end of the page.");
```

If you wanted to load content dynamically, you would have to use the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method and use the code above in the callback.